# AD authentication with one LDAP failed but passed with another LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

From the following website, I found codes to perform java AD authentication.

http://java2db.com/jndi-ldap-programming/solution-to-sslhandshakeexception

The followings are the codes:

MySSLSocketFactory.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
    public MySSLSocketFactory() {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new DummyTrustmanager()}, new SecureRandom());
            socketFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
    public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
        return new MySSLSocketFactory();
    }
    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return socketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }
    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return socketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String string, int num, boolean bool) throws IOException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(socket, string, num, bool);
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String string, int num) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(string, num);
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String string, int num, InetAddress netAdd, int i)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(string, num, netAdd, i);
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress netAdd, int num) throws IOException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(netAdd, num);
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress netAdd1, int num, InetAddress netAdd2, int i) throws IOException {
        return socketFactory.createSocket(netAdd1, num, netAdd2, i);
    }
}
```

DummyTrustmanager.java

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class DummyTrustmanager implements X509TrustManager {
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String string) throws CertificateException
    {
    }
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String string) throws CertificateException
    {
    }
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
    {
    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
    }

}
```

TestAD.java

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

public class TestAD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //String url = "ldaps://abc.company.com:636";
            String url = "ldaps://xyz.group.com:636";
            String conntype = "simple";
            // String id = "abc@abc.company.com";
            String id = "xyz.group.com";
            //String password = "abcpassword";
            String password = "xyzpassword";
            Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
            environment.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "MySSLSocketFactory");
            environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, conntype);
            environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, id);
            environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            DirContext ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(environment);
            System.out.println("Bind successful");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My company has a few subsidiaries, and they have their own LDAPs. When I run TestAD against my company ABC's LDAP, it works fine. But when I run it against the subsidiary XYZ's LDAP, I got the following exception:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: xyz.group.com:636
[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xyz.group.com found.]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:219)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2791)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
        at TestAD.main(TestAD.java:26)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xyz.group.com found.
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:931)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:877)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xyz.group.com found.
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:214)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:459)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1125)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1092)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 12 more
```

What could be the reason for the failure? I did not import ABC's or XYZ's certificate into my trust store. Why does it work fine for ABC but not for XYZ? Could it be that XYZ is expecting my certificate?

Comment: To add on, I am able to telnet to xyz.group.com 636, so the connection is not an issue.

Comment: From what is reflecting in the exception "`java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xyz.group.com found`", the subject alternate name for DNS "xyz.group.com" is not present in the certificate being used in your application. Please make sure that you're using a certificate for communication which is trusted by other AD environment.

Comment: Do you mean 'failed with one LDAP *server* but passed with another LDAP *server*'? LDAP is a protocol, not a thing.

Comment: @user207421 lol.. hopefully a protocol is a thing right ? ;) thank you (again) for your contribution (condescending attitude) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This caused by the *endpoint identification algorithms*, it checks the host name in your configuration matches the host name in your remote LDAPS TLS server certificate, and that those host names are valid.

Given this error `No subject alternative DNS name matching xyz.group.com found`, it must be that "xyz.group.com" doesn't match your ldap server certificate, while "abc.company.com" does match.

Java 8u181 brought some changes in *core-libs/javax.naming* and updated how secure LDAP connections are handled (cf. [release note](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u181-relnotes-4479407.html)) :

> Endpoint identification has been enabled on
>   LDAPS connections.
>
> To improve the robustness of LDAPS (secure LDAP over TLS) connections,
>   endpoint identification algorithms have been enabled by default.
>
> Note that there may be situations where some applications that were
>   previously able to successfully connect to an LDAPS server may no
>   longer be able to do so. Such applications may, if they deem
>   appropriate, disable endpoint identification using a new system
>   property: `com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification`.
>
> Define this system property (or set it to true) to disable endpoint
>   identification algorithms.

Disabling the endpoint identification algorithms is a workaround, the long term solution is to fix the server certificate so that it matches "xyz.group.com" hostname.